# win32k.sys mapping address in the session space

Tags: windows, session, kernel, driver

My question:

*when win32k.sys is loaded into the session space, does it get the same base address in every session?*

Details:

I'm writing a kernel-mode device driver for Windows (32 bit). It loads as a standard WDM driver into the **system space** (global kernel-mode memory) during the system boot.

However in some situations I need to access functions exported by win32k.sys. To be exact, I'm writing a sort of a driver that needs sometimes to pretend as a display driver.

I **may not** statically import those functions (means, import them via executable import table). This is because win32k.sys is loaded during the later stage when sessions are created. Moreover, it's loaded into the **session space**.

Nevertheless I've found the workaround. During the session creation I import the needed functions dynamically. I use `ZwQuerySystemInformation` with `SystemModuleInformation` to find the base address of win32k.sys **in the current session**. Then using this base address I analyze it to find the export directory of win32k.sys and obtain the needed function pointers.

Currently for every session I keep a separate array of imported functions. However practically those functions are always the same in all the sessions. Means - win32k.sys is mapped into the same address belonging to the session space in every session.

Hence, my question is, is there a guarantee that win32k.sys will be mapped into the same address in all the sessions?

Apart from saving some memory this will make things easier for me. Currently in order to call such a function I need a session-specific context where the function pointers are stored.

Answer (score 3):

My experience is that **win32k.sys** base address is the same in the context of all processes the driver is mapped. During its initialization, **win32k.sys** calls `ntoskrnl.exe` to create Object Type kernel objects for desktops, window stations and possibly other objects used by the driver. These kernel objects must be at the same addresses in context of all processes to keep the kernel data structures consistent (for example, there is an array of pointers to all Object Type objects inside `ntoskrnl.exe` module).

Moreover, **win32k.sys** contains a system call table (`win32k!W32pServiceTable`). Address of the table is, again, stored in a fixed location in `ntoskrnl.exe` (`nt!KeServiceDescriptorTableshadow`).

So, if the **win32k.sys** driver was mapped to different addresses in different session, `ntoskrnl.exe` must behave the same. And this is not true (such behavior would cause additional problems, for example, with `SYSENTER/SYSCALL`). But I did not see this fact written in any official documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I am not very sure but I guess the answer is YES. Win32k.sys is just another (special) dll file, and every dll file on Windows has a base address in its PE header. For win32k.sys which is provided by the Windows(I think), the base address should never conflict with other system dll (.sys) files.

To be safe, you can make your program a little bit flexible. At the beginning, you assume the address is same. But you check the address before you actually call it. In that way, the system will not hang because of bad address, at least.

Comment: This makes sense. However I won't be able to write the program in the *flexible* way you suggest. Because to be safe I'll have to provide the per-session context information that has the function pointers. The even fact that those pointers are usually the same in all the sessions - doesn't help me too much.

Comment: OK. Just another thought. Since it is a .sys file, it resides in the kernel space and is shared by all the user level processes and sessions. Therefore, its address should be fixed. Moreover, I cannot find any situation that the address will be different for different sessions. Why it could be different?